# Https api access issues

Tags: bash, api, ssl, curl, https

Good afternoon, dear community!
I ask for help from those who had the relevant experience.
I am making an API request to https://ssl.croinform.ru:450. For example, an authentication request: curl -k POST https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test?Type=Login&Login=testUser&Password=testPassword but I get the error. The error text differs depending on the environment where I am running the curl command.
On windows I experiment in git bash (curl version 7.77.0) and Cygwin64 (curl version 7.78.0), get the same error: curl: (35) error: 14094410: SSL routines: ssl3_read_bytes: sslv3 alert handshake failure.
В CentOS7 (curl version 7.78.0): curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

The service provides certificates that need to be installed on your OS: cacer.p7b, ssl.croinform.cer. As recommended in the service documentation, on windows I installed them in Trusted Root Certification Authorities. There is no support recommendation for CentOS7, but I put the certificates at / etc / pki / ca-trust / source / anchors / and ran the update-ca-trust enable and update-ca-trust extract commands. These actions do not solve the problem.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your error shows the protocol to use is SSL version 3 and the handshake is failing to agree to use this protocol to communicate with SSL.

plus this may be unsupported now, the latest TLS versions are TLS 1.1 and 1.2

you could try a different protocol version for example,

`curl --tlsv1.2`

To use tls 1.2 but have a look at the documentation for other protocols also.

If this is a test you can allow insecure connections with the `curl -k` parameter

Comment: Shaqil, thank you very much for your advice!

I tried the following:
curl --tlsv1.1 POST https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test?Type=Login&Login=testUser&Password=testPassword

As well as --tlsv1.1 and -k (substituted instead of --tlsv1.1).
Unfortunately the same error:
curl --tlsv1.1 POST https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test?Type=Login

Comment: Now I have done a little differently:
cat cacer.p7b >> certRepo
cat ssl.croinform.cer >> certRepo
Now I am passing certRepo in the request.

I also added --connect-to for the request in CentOs - this got rid of the errors: Failed to resolve host: POST curl.
Now the request looks like this:
curl curl --cacert certRepo --connect-to POST https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test?Type=Login&Login=User&Password=testPassword

And the error in windows and CentOs is like this:
curl: (77) error configuring certificate, checking location: CAfile: certRepo CApath: none

Comment: Package ca-certificates it installed. Simply, this package advise to install it when an error appears about which I wrote above.